# Save file with number increment in last of the file

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio

I'm struggling to get this code to work, basically the idea is for the app to save the file and if the file exists then I want it to add a number on end that increases for example: `file.txt`, `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`

But it saves the first file then the app crashes, it's something to do with the while loop, I've not tried a `for` function yet.

```
// txtTiltetosave = The Title that is used by the save function (this works)

int num = 0;
File myFile = new File("mydir);
if (myFile.exists()) {
       while (myFile.exists()) {
           txtTitletosave = "file"+(num++);
       }
} else {
       txtTitletosave = "file";
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You don't need a while loop.

Comment: What would you suggest then?  Without a while loop it would only make two files. eg: file.txt, file1.txt. It Wouldn't increase

Comment: You are even missing an apostrophe, is difficult to figure out what you want.

Comment: Is it? Id just like to add a number on end of a save file that increases every time I save. E.G: file.txt, file1.txt, file 2.txt etc

Comment: `while (myFile.exists()) {
           txtTitletosave = "file"+(num++);` That is an endless loop. It will never end as nothing changes in the condition.

Comment: `new File("mydir);` Why are you calling a file 'mydir'? Moreover you cannot only use a file name in the `File` class. You should provide there a full path. So use it with the directory where you wanna save your file. Please post better code where you start with the destination directory.

Comment: Sorry @greenapps but I felt Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"file" as I wasn't at my pc at the time just seemed quite long and I couldn't remember the whole thing so I just put mydir.

Comment: Adapt your code here! Post complete code. And without that endless loop. Dont only say sorry but try again. Try better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for everyone who helped the two answers, didn't work (for me) But they definitely gave me an idea, and this works just how I wanted it to.

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/mydir" + "file.txt");
  if (!myFile.exists()) {
        txtTitletosave = "file";
  } else {
       int count = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/mydir").list().length;
       txtTitletosave = "file"+count;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this - 
Initially find out how many files are there in the given directory using this code, if there are none, create a new file.

```
File file = new File("C:/MyFolder/");
if(!file.exists()){
  txtTitletosave = "file";
}
else {
int count = file.listFiles().length;
txtTitletosave = "file"+count;
}
```

Let me know if this helps, haven't tried it though.

Comment: I'll  have to try it later. But I Dont see why that wouldn't work. Logically. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code that will help you

```
   File myFile = new File("mydir");
    String txtTitletosave;
    if (myFile.exists()) {
        String [] array = myFile.getName().split("\\.");
        String fileName = array[0];
        String lastNumber = fileName.substring(fileName.length() -1);
        int numberToIncrease = Integer.parseInt(lastNumber);

            txtTitletosave = "file"+(++numberToIncrease);

    } else {
        txtTitletosave = "file";
    }
```

Even the code is long and it can be refactored. but for the purpose of clarity I have written step by step. Hope that helps you.

Comment: When I get a chance I'll try that don't see why that wouldn't work. Thank you